# Scala - better way to reformat/grouping List/Map to map

Tags: scala

I have the problem of coding best way or proper way to the grouping/formatting in functional manner  a list.

The sample List is this

```
 val list = List (
        Map(
          "name" -> "AAA",
          "id" -> "1",
          "category" -> "1",
          "sub_category" -> "1"
        ),

        Map(
          "name" -> "BBB",
          "id" -> "2",
          "category" -> "1",
          "sub_category" -> "2"
        ),

        Map(
          "name" -> "CCC",
          "id" -> "3",
          "category" -> "1",
          "sub_category" -> "2"
        ),

        Map(
          "name" -> "DDD",
          "id" -> "4",
          "category" -> "2",
          "sub_category" -> "1"
        ),

        Map(
          "name" -> "EEE",
          "id" -> "5",
          "category" -> "2",
          "sub_category" -> "2"
        )
      )
```

I wanted to group by category and sub_category. The expected result is this

```
Map(
        2 -> Map(
          2 -> MutableList(
            Map(name -> EEE, id -> 5, category -> 2, sub_category -> 2)
          ),

          1 -> MutableList(
            Map(name -> DDD, id -> 4, category -> 2, sub_category -> 1)
          )
        ),

        1 -> Map(
          2 -> MutableList(
            Map(name -> BBB, id -> 2, category -> 1, sub_category -> 2),
            Map(name -> CCC, id -> 3, category -> 1, sub_category -> 2)
          ),

          1 -> MutableList(
            Map(name -> AAA, id -> 1, category -> 1, sub_category -> 1)
          )
        )
      )
```

The expected out put can contain List or MutableList and I have done the code like this

```
val filtered:mutable.Map[Int,mutable.Map[Int,mutable.MutableList[Map[String,String]]]] =  mutable.Map()

      for(each <- list) {

        if(filtered.contains(each("category").toInt)) {

          if(filtered(each("category").toInt).contains(each("sub_category").toInt)) {

            filtered(each("category").toInt)(each("sub_category").toInt) += each

          } else {
            filtered(each("category").toInt) += (
              each("sub_category").toInt -> mutable.MutableList(each)
              )
          }
        } else {
          filtered += (
            each("category").toInt -> mutable.Map(each("sub_category").toInt -> mutable.MutableList(each))
            )
        }
      }
```

I'm getting the result and this is not the functional way I wanted a proper way to do this Could anyone please help me ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gets the result you're looking for.

```
list.groupBy(_("category")).mapValues(_.groupBy(_("sub_category")))
```

I have to say it looks like you're using `Map` where a well designed `case class` would be the better way to go.